# Where do Russian and Chinese airliner manufacturers test their airliners?

Tags: airliner, flight-testing

Airbus test their plane on [Toulouse Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toulouse%E2%80%93Blagnac_Airport), and Boeing test on [Boeing field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_Field).

How about Russian airliners Ilyushin & Tupolev and Chinese Airliners [Comac](http://Comac) ?

Comment: Note, that this only applies to the basic tests. In the later phases of testing the aircraft needs to fly to windy places, cold places, hot places and so on, which generally takes it all over the world.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Almost all Russian (Soviet) aircrafts were tested in the Zhukovsky Airfield (Ramenskoye Airport) near Moscow.

The Comac is building a Flight Test center at Dongying, Shandong province near the Dongying Shengli Airport. The flight test of aircrafts are expected to be carried out from here.

As Peter noted, Antonov test their aircrafts at Kiev Airport, including An 225, the largest aircraft in world.

Comment: Antonov is doing their testing at an airport northwest of Kiev, and did this even in Soviet times.

Comment: You are right. In my defense, Antonov is Ukrainian, not Russian.

Comment: … and they build few civilian airliners. I didn't mean to criticize your answer, just add to it.

Comment: I didn't take it that way. I was using a loophole :). Anyway, edited.